# Same URL for every page ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, url

I have multiple pages in my application, if I navigate through pages the URL changes accordingly, What I want is that whenever I navigate to any page the URL should not change, it should stay same doesn't matter which page I visit.

I tried URL Mapping in web.config but it is not working. it's loosing all css also since I want same url for all pages it's not letting me do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: Second @mason's question. If it is a public facing website, doing this could severely hurt your SEO if you do not use the proper canonical, etc. rules

Comment: We have a client, and it's there requirement. This is not a public website

Comment: Well if they're your client, you should give them proper advice. Find out why they have that requirement. Find out what problem they're trying to solve - likely there's a better way of accomplishing whatever it is they truly want.

Comment: @mason They are doing this for security purpose, for e.g. in my application I have a folder called Administration and inside that folder we have different pages related to administrative tasks.

Now According to them a attacker should not be able to see the Adminitration folder and its page name

Comment: So? The way to fix that is not to force every page to have the same URL. Implement authorization. Check that they're allowed to access the page when they attempt to access it. Redirect them elsewhere if they don't have the necessary permission.